# Query statistic is taking 99% of the query time

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, entity-attribute-value

I have an SQL query which take about 1.81s seconds to execute. I profiled it in phpMyAdmin and I saw that 99% of the time is spend on 'statistics'.

Interestingly if I add one more join, the time goes up to about 23 seconds and if I remove 1 join the time goes down to about 0.26 seconds.

I have tried to put the `product_id =`  in the where the the `attribute_id =`  in the join. It does not improve the performance and the 'statistics' still use 99% of the time.

I have tried `group by p.id` which does improve performance a little but 'statistics' still use 98% of the time.

**Is there a way to improve the 'statistics' performance or just to disable it?**

Note: I do have indexes on all PK/FK.

***Useful information***

sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d37a0/1/0)

the query return about 150 rows.

```
ss_product table has 1k rows
ss_product_attributes has 30 rows
ss_product_attribute_varchars has 5000 rows
ss_product_attribute_decimals has 10000 rows
```

***The schema***

```
ss_products has many ss_product_attribute_varchars
ss_products has many ss_product_attribute_decimals
ss_product_attribute_varchars belongs to ss_product_attributes
ss_product_attribute_decimals belongs to ss_product_attributes

-------------
-ss_products-
-------------
- PK - id   -
-------------

--------------------------------
-ss_product_attribute_varchars-
--------------------------------
- PK - id                      -
- FK - product_id              -
- FK - attribute_id            -
--------------------------------

--------------------------------
-ss_products_attribute_decimals-
--------------------------------
- PK - id                      -
- FK - product_id              -
- FK - attribute_id            -
--------------------------------

------------------------
-ss_products_attributes-
------------------------
- PK - id              -
------------------------
```

***The profiling***

```
Starting                 101 µs
Checking Permissions     6 µs
Checking Permissions     2 µs
Checking Permissions     2 µs
Checking Permissions     2 µs
Checking Permissions     1 µs
Checking Permissions     2 µs
Checking Permissions     2 µs
Checking Permissions     2 µs
Checking Permissions     2 µs
Checking Permissions     3 µs
Opening Tables           47 µs
System Lock              10 µs
Init                     35 µs
Optimizing               21 µs
Statistics               1.8 s      //1.8seconds!!!!
Preparing                46 µs
Executing                3 µs
Sending Data             41 ms
End                      7 µs
Query End                4 µs
Closing Tables           12 µs
Freeing Items            463 µs
Logging Slow Query       3 µs
Cleaning Up              9 µs
```

***The query***

```
select
    aa.value as attribute_a,
    bb.value as attribute_b,
    cc.value as attribute_c,
    dd.value as attribute_d,
    ee.value as attribute_e,
    ff.value as attribute_f,
    gg.value as attribute_g,
    hh.value as attribute_h,
    ii.value as attribute_i
from ss_products as p
    inner join ss_product_attribute_varchars as aa
    on p.id = aa.product_id
    inner join ss_product_attribute_varchars as bb
    on p.id = bb.product_id
    inner join ss_product_attribute_varchars as cc
    on p.id = cc.product_id
    inner join ss_product_attribute_decimals as dd
    on p.id = dd.product_id
    inner join ss_product_attribute_decimals as ee
    on p.id = ee.product_id
    inner join ss_product_attribute_decimals as ff
    on p.id = ff.product_id
    inner join ss_product_attribute_varchars as gg
    on p.id = gg.product_id
    INNER JOIN ss_product_attribute_varchars AS hh 
    ON p.id = hh.product_id 
    INNER JOIN ss_product_attribute_varchars AS ii 
    ON p.id = ii.product_id 
where 
    aa.attribute_id = 8 AND 
    bb.attribute_id = 6 AND 
    cc.attribute_id = 7 AND 
    dd.attribute_id = 9 and
    ee.attribute_id = 10 and
    ff.attribute_id = 11 AND
    gg.attribute_id = 20 AND 
    hh.attribute_id = 2 AND
    ii.attribute_id = 3
```

**The Explain**

```
id| select_type| table  | type   | possible_keys                                         |key                                          |key_len| ref                 | rows| Extra
1 | SIMPLE     | gg     | ref    | fk_product_attribute_varchars_products1_idx,fk_pro... | attribute_id                                | 4     | const               | 143 |
1 | SIMPLE     | aa     | ref    | fk_product_attribute_varchars_products1_idx,fk_pro... | fk_product_attribute_varchars_products1_idx | 4     | my_id.gg.product_id | 2   | Using where
1 | SIMPLE     | cc     | ref    | fk_product_attribute_varchars_products1_idx,fk_pro... | fk_product_attribute_varchars_products1_idx | 4     | my_id.gg.product_id | 2   | Using where
1 | SIMPLE     | bb     | ref    | fk_product_attribute_varchars_products1_idx,fk_pro... | fk_product_attribute_varchars_products1_idx | 4     | my_id.gg.product_id | 2   | Using where
1 | SIMPLE     | ii     | ref    | fk_product_attribute_varchars_products1_idx,fk_pro... | fk_product_attribute_varchars_products1_idx | 4     | my_id.aa.product_id | 2   | Using where
1 | SIMPLE     | p      | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                               | PRIMARY                                     | 4     | my_id.aa.product_id | 1   | Using where; Using index
1 | SIMPLE     | dd     | ref    | fk_product_attribute_decimals_products1_idx,fk_pro... | fk_product_attribute_decimals_products1_idx | 4     | my_id.cc.product_id | 2   | Using where
1 | SIMPLE     | ee     | ref    | fk_product_attribute_decimals_products1_idx,fk_pro... | fk_product_attribute_decimals_products1_idx | 4     | my_id.ii.product_id | 2   | Using where
1 | SIMPLE     | ff     | ref    | fk_product_attribute_decimals_products1_idx,fk_pro... | fk_product_attribute_decimals_products1_idx | 4     | my_id.p.id          | 2   | Using where
1 | SIMPLE     | hh     | ref    | fk_product_attribute_varchars_products1_idx,fk_pro... | fk_product_attribute_varchars_products1_idx | 4     | my_id.cc.product_id | 2   | Using where
```

**Complete profile** (as asked by Raymond Nijland)

```
+----------------------+----------+----------+------------+-------------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------+-----------------+---------------+-------------+
| Status               | Duration | CPU_user | CPU_system | Context_voluntary | Context_involuntary | Block_ops_in | Block_ops_out | Messages_sent | Messages_received | Page_faults_major | Page_faults_minor | Swaps | Source_function | Source_file   | Source_line |
+----------------------+----------+----------+------------+-------------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------+-----------------+---------------+-------------+
| starting             | 0.000151 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |            NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | NULL            | NULL          |        NULL |
| checking permissions | 0.000005 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |            NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_parse.cc  |        4751 |
| checking permissions | 0.000002 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |            NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_parse.cc  |        4751 |
| checking permissions | 0.000003 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |            NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_parse.cc  |        4751 |
| checking permissions | 0.000002 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |            NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_parse.cc  |        4751 |
| checking permissions | 0.000003 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |            NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_parse.cc  |        4751 |
| checking permissions | 0.000002 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |            NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_parse.cc  |        4751 |
| checking permissions | 0.000005 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |            NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_parse.cc  |        4751 |
| checking permissions | 0.000002 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |            NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_parse.cc  |        4751 |
| checking permissions | 0.000002 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |            NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_parse.cc  |        4751 |
| checking permissions | 0.000005 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |            NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_parse.cc  |        4751 |
| Opening tables       | 0.000051 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |            NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_base.cc   |        4838 |
| System lock          | 0.000016 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |            NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | lock.cc       |         299 |
| init                 | 0.000046 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |            NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_select.cc |        2560 |
| optimizing           | 0.000031 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |            NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_select.cc |         869 |
| statistics           | 1.419911 | 1.404009 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |            NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_select.cc |        1060 |
| preparing            | 0.000050 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |            NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_select.cc |        1082 |
| executing            | 0.000003 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |            NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_select.cc |        1829 |
| Sending data         | 0.018508 | 0.015600 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |            NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_select.cc |        2371 |
| end                  | 0.000007 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |            NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_select.cc |        2596 |
| query end            | 0.000004 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |            NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_parse.cc  |        4440 |
| closing tables       | 0.000018 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |            NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_parse.cc  |        4492 |
| freeing items        | 0.000110 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |            NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_parse.cc  |        5640 |
| logging slow query   | 0.000004 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |            NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_parse.cc  |        1461 |
| cleaning up          | 0.000008 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |            NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | <unknown>       | sql_parse.cc  |        1417 |
+----------------------+----------+----------+------------+-------------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------+-----------------+---------------+-------------+
```

Comment: What does EXPLAIN say?

Comment: @Barmar updated the question with the EXPLAIN

Comment: @Gab side note omg next time use aliases that mean something not aa bb cc or you may want to try naming your alias well banging your head on the keyboard..

Comment: Are you running this DB on NFS storage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Made an answer out off it because an comment doenst support code formatting.

Statistics in profile output is defined within this part in the C++ source code off MySQL

```
 /* Calculate how to do the join */
thd_proc_info(thd, "statistics");
if (make_join_statistics(this, select_lex->leaf_tables, conds, &keyuse) ||
thd->is_fatal_error)
{
DBUG_PRINT("error",("Error: make_join_statistics() failed"));
DBUG_RETURN(1);
}
```

But you still need to run

```
SHOW PROFILE ALL FOR QUERY n
```

So we can see if the query is CPU or Disk I/O bounded.

**I advise to use UNION ALL or use divide and conquer strategy to separate the querys**

Comment: and the MySQL server version?

Comment: MySql version 5.5.27, InnoDB version 1.1.8

Comment: @Gab i dont have the Sources off this version.. but the high CPU_User value is an indication that the CPU is likly most the limiting factor... so I advise you to use UNION ALL or use divide and conquer strategy to separate the querys

Comment: I am not familiar with the devide and conquer strategy. And i dont see how i could use UNION ALL in this case. Could you guive a brief example?

Comment: Can you post the tables and some example data on sqlfiddle?? http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40283/discussion-between-gab-and-raymond-nijland)

Comment: @Gab ive totally lost the scope off your comment do you still need an fix for your question??