# Slow Inner JOIN of 6 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Sorry my SQL knowledge is amateur.

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5640d/1
Please click the link above to refer to the database structure and query.

I have 6 tables,each data will take only one row in each table,and I have 3 same columns `Custgroup`,`RandomNumber` and `user_id` in all 6 tables.

`Custgroup` is a group name,within the group each data is with an unique `RandomNumber`.

The query is pretty slow at first run(took several seconds to few minutes randomly),after that will be fast,but for first few pages only.If I click to page 20 or 30+,it will be non stop loading(Just took about 5 minutes just now).And the data is not much,only 5000 rows,which will be in big trouble in future.And I still haven't add any WHERE clause yet as I need to have filtering for each columns in my website.(not my idea,requested by my boss).

I tried to changed it to LEFT JOIN,JOIN and any other ways I can found,but the loading is still slow.

I added INDEX for user_id,Custgroup AND RandomNumber of all tables.
Anyway to solve this problem?I never good in using JOIN,really slow for my database.

Or please let me know if my table structure is really bad,I'm willing to redo it.

Thanks.

**Edited

RUN EXPLAIN:

```
    id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra

    1   SIMPLE  tE  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    5685    

    1   SIMPLE  tA  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    6072    Using join buffer

    1   SIMPLE  t1  ref     user_id,Custgroup,RandomNumber  RandomNumber    23  func    1   Using where

    1   SIMPLE  tB  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    5868    Using where; Using join buffer

    1   SIMPLE  tC  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    6043    Using where; Using join buffer

    1   SIMPLE  tD  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    5906    Using where; Using join buffer


    Keyname Type    Unique  Packed  Column  Cardinality Collation   Null    Comment
    PRIMARY BTREE   Yes No  ID  6033    A       
    RandomNumber    BTREE   No  No  RandomNumber    6033    A       
    Custgroup   BTREE   No  No  Custgroup   1   A       
    user_id BTREE   No  No  user_id 1   A
```

Edited: EXPLAIN EXTENDED  .....

```
    id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    filtered    Extra
    1   SIMPLE  tE  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    6084    100.00  
    1   SIMPLE  t1  ref     user_id,Custgroup,RandomNumber  RandomNumber    23  func    1   100.00  Using where
    1   SIMPLE  tB  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    5664    100.00  Using where; Using join buffer
    1   SIMPLE  tC  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    5976    100.00  Using where; Using join buffer
    1   SIMPLE  tA  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    6065    100.00  Using where; Using join buffer
    1   SIMPLE  tD  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    6286    100.00  Using where; Using join buffer
```

Comment: Please don't tag your question [tag:sql-server]. Post the table structures, indexes, `EXPLAIN` statement...

Comment: Run EXPLAIN on the query so we can see the indexes used

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO Sorry my mistake,clicked accidentally.

Comment: Also please don't tag your question php. It has nothing to do with your question

Comment: Okay sorry for all the tags.

Comment: @Sam D Sorry not sure how to create a table in stackoverflow,I just briefly paste the output first.

Comment: no no worries I just want an EXPLAIN query. That is EPLAIN YOURQUERYHERE run this and paste the results.

Comment: @Sam D I paste it,but looks messy ,sorry for that

Comment: @HLGEM  I see,thanks for your explanation.Is there any idea how to handle this kind of big database?

Comment: add some indexes on the columns you use to join. Your query is not using relavant indexes

Comment: @SamD Oh I thought I added it?I clicked More->Add Index of the columns I used to join,is it correct?I do the same for all tables.And I just paste the Indexes table of one of the table.Thank you.

Comment: This would be a good case to use http://sqlfiddle.com/ to create your tables and add some sample data, so we can see what the data looks like.

Comment: @NWest Ok thanks for the link,will do it now.

Comment: Well what can i say SQL optimisation is like art..  you still may have an problem with `RandomNumber  RandomNumber    23  func    1   Using wher`   looks like an convert function is run on that join.. can you run these queries `EXPLAIN EXTENDED your query; SHOW WARNINGS;`  the SHOW warnings part needs to be executed directly after the first query then you need to paste and post the message here.. this is the SQL after the MySQL optimizer (note may not be valid SQL code).. you will also see that the SQL optimizer merges the  ON statements to an WHERE statement.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thanks for your reply.I run the query and just pasted it below the question,but sorry for the messy.

Comment: @NWest Hi I finished it,here is the link : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5640d/1 Thank you.

Comment: @Irene Ling you need to run first the query `EXPLAIN EXTENDED your query;` and directly after `SHOW WARNINGS;` then you get the SQL optimizer SQL code in the message... EXPLAIN EXTENDED only adds an extra column filterd..

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thanks for your guide.But sorry I tried to run the query,but can only see a table like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/38e4f/11 ,am I doing it correctly?

Comment: @Irene Ling yes you are doing it correcty ... but SQLfiddle does is wrong because there is an query in between

Comment: @RaymondNijland I see,i run with my own server but there is no other message but just the table.I will try again,and really thanks for trying to help me,I appreciate it.So much things to learn from you guys,thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logical indexing for such a structure would have to be

```
CREATE INDEX UserAddedRecord1_ndx ON UserAddedRecord1 (user_id, Custgroup, RandomNumber);
CREATE INDEX UserAddedRecord1_A_ndx ON UserAddedRecord1_A (Custgroup, RandomNumber);
CREATE INDEX UserAddedRecord1_B_ndx ON UserAddedRecord1_B (Custgroup, RandomNumber);
CREATE INDEX UserAddedRecord1_C_ndx ON UserAddedRecord1_C (Custgroup, RandomNumber);
CREATE INDEX UserAddedRecord1_D_ndx ON UserAddedRecord1_D (Custgroup, RandomNumber);
CREATE INDEX UserAddedRecord1_E_ndx ON UserAddedRecord1_E (Custgroup, RandomNumber);
```

And if you are going to add `WHERE` clauses, they ought to go in the relevant index *before* the `JOIN` conditions (provided you run an equal or `IN` search, e.g. City = "New York"). For example if City is in UserAddedRecord1_B, then UserAddedRecord1_B_ndx ought to be `City, Custgroup, RandomNumber`.

But at this point, I have to ask, *why*? Apparently you have records always for the same user. For example:

```
t1.Cell,t1.Name,t1.Gender,t1.Birthday
tA.Email,tA.State,tA.Address,tA.City,tA.Postcode
```

...it is obvious that you can't have two different users here (and having Email in the same block as Postcode tells me this was not really intended as a one-to-many relation).

```
tB.Website,tB.Description,
tC.Model,tC.Capital,tC.Registry,tC.NoEmployees,
tD.SetUpDate,tD.PeopleInCharge,tD.Certification,tD.AddOEM,
tD.NoResearcher,tD.RoomSize,tD.RegisterMessage,
tE.WebsiteName,tE.OriginalWebsite,tE.QQ,tE.MSN,tE.Skype
```

These are all portions of a single large "user information form", divided in (optional?) sections.

I surmise that this structure arose from some kind of legacy/framework system that mapped a form submission *section* to a *table*. So that someone may have an entry in tables B, C and E, and someone else in tables A, C and D.

**If this is true**, and if `user_id` is the same for all tables, then one way of having this go faster is to explicitly add a condition on `user_id` for each table, and suitably modify indexes and JOINs:

```
CREATE INDEX UserAddedRecord1_ndx ON UserAddedRecord1 (user_id, Custgroup, RandomNumber);
CREATE INDEX UserAddedRecord1_A_ndx ON UserAddedRecord1_A (user_id, Custgroup, RandomNumber);
CREATE INDEX UserAddedRecord1_B_ndx ON UserAddedRecord1_B (user_id, Custgroup, RandomNumber);
CREATE INDEX UserAddedRecord1_C_ndx ON UserAddedRecord1_C (user_id, Custgroup, RandomNumber);
CREATE INDEX UserAddedRecord1_D_ndx ON UserAddedRecord1_D (user_id, Custgroup, RandomNumber);
CREATE INDEX UserAddedRecord1_E_ndx ON UserAddedRecord1_E (user_id, Custgroup, RandomNumber);

... FROM UserAddedRecord1 t1
JOIN UserAddedRecord1_A tA USING (user_id, CustGroup, RandomNumber)
JOIN UserAddedRecord1_B tB USING (user_id, CustGroup, RandomNumber)
JOIN UserAddedRecord1_C tC USING (user_id, CustGroup, RandomNumber)
JOIN UserAddedRecord1_D tD USING (user_id, CustGroup, RandomNumber)
JOIN UserAddedRecord1_E tE USING (user_id, CustGroup, RandomNumber)
     WHERE t1.user_id = '1'
```

## Try [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/38e4f/2)

The thing to do would be to incorporate all the tables into *one* table with all the fields in one row and then, maybe, for legacy purposes, you might create `VIEWs` that look like tables 1, A, B, C, D and E, each with a "vertical" partition of the tuple. But the big `SELECT` you would run on the complete table having all the fields (and you would save on duplicate columns, too).

Comment: Really thanks for your reply and explanation.will learn it,Actually my website is for people to upload csv and store their database,and each database(CSV) uploaded can have a groupname,but the available headers of csv are nearly 40,which is quite a lot,so to maintain each table has only 10 columns instead of 40 columns in one table,I separate it into 6 tables,and thinking to use RandomNumber,user_id to join it.Not sure if this structure is correct...I'm now trying the new query with the newly created index,but still slow at first run.

Comment: +1 This is completly correct @Irene Ling keep in mind that joining to much tables (even self joins) can be expensive for the CPU -> post off mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19691538/query-statistic-is-taking-99-of-the-query-time/19693373#19693373 scroll up to question you can see that the topicstarter has many self joined tables..

Comment: If you work with MySQL, forty columns are **nothing to worry about**! Rather, think well over the datatypes of each column. For example, if a field is going to always be a number, declare it `INTEGER` of suitable size. Place all data in the same table and be happy :-)

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thanks for the link,yes he has a lot of tables to joined.Will learn from the topic,really thanks.

Comment: @Iserni Sorry for delayed response.Yes I'm using MySQL,I just tried with all 40 columns in one table,and it is so much faster than separated tables.I always read from articles that mentioning one table with more than 10 columns is bad in design,but guess this time I will just go with it.Thanks for the tips and all the helps,really appreciate it.

Comment: @IreneLing, to paraphrase a famous physicist, *the number of columns in a table should be made as small as possible,* **but no smaller than that** :-). Tightly coupled data on the same entity just *have* to go in the same table. You may want to look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization